# What is return type <T> T?

Tags: java

What is the return type of `<T> T` I can understand the return type T (T can be an object of any type) but what is the significance of `<T>` ?

Comment: Go through [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Comment: More specifically [This page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF you're in a class, that has a declared generic type, your method might look like this:

```
public T someMethod();
```

However, if you're not in a class that has some generic type declared, you can declare one for just that method scope.

```
public <T> T someMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

we entered into a program the `return` keyword and that program will terminate from that scope.

```java
    import java.util.*;

    class Example {
         public static void main(String args[]) {  
             for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                 if (i == 4) {
                     return;
                 }

                 System.out.println(i);
             }
         }
    }
```